# Spring and CAS using Spring Security :: Ticket left in URL killing bookmarks

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I have setup an application that uses Spring and the built in Spring Security CAS implementation. Everything seems to be working fine, and the users can login okay and all is fine. That is until you attempt to bookmark a page.

It seems that our system is retaining the ticket query parameter after the CasAuthenticationFilter fires in the Security Filter Chain.

We end up with users having URLs that contain the ticket query parameter in them. If they bookmark a page, and then return to it, they get a ticket doesn't exist error.

Is this expected behavior? I remember looking in the Jasig client implementation and they seem to scrub it there, but not in the Spring Sec impl?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Java-based CAS validation filters support RedirectAfterValidation. This will refresh the page and remove the ticket parameter.

See https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Using+the+CAS+Client+3.1+with+Spring+Security

Comment: I had originally saw that this was on by default, but after debugging through the CAS client I found that the SAMl11 tickets were using the id of SAMLart instead of ticket. So I added the following together and its working great now.   `<property name="artifactParameterName" value="ticket" />
        <property name="redirectAfterValidation" value="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

Do a redirect (to a URL without the ticket parameter) after the user is redirected back to your app for ticket validation.